# Is HTTP POST data modified in transit?

Tags: http, http-post

I am looking for instances where HTTP post data is modified (even slightly) in transit. I am working on a protocol that wants to guarantee integrity of post data. Modifying 1 character would make the integrity check fail which is hardly a robust mechanism.

If I can get an overview of all proxies, firewalls, etc, that modify POST data and in what manner, I might be able to make the integrity check more robust for requests passing through these services.

The type of modifications I am looking for are:

- Adding removing whitespaces, CR
- Upper to lower case conversions

I am not willing to tolerate modifications of the POST data which would change it's meaning since this is a breach of integrity. I haven't found much information on the subject so if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: A comprehensive overview probably doesn't exist (and list questions are generally off topic here I'm afraid.) In general, though, I don't think this happens often, as the type of modifications you list would break things (like a file upload). What is the real-world use case for this?

Comment: Integrity checking of requests belonging to a session as a countermeasure to session hijacking.